# Clue how to Integrate $\int_0^1 \left ( \int_{x^{1/3}}^1 (1+y^8)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dy \right ) dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I suspect that I maybe should use variable substitution, but am not able to get anywhere. The answer is supposed to be $\dfrac{1}{4} (\ln(\sqrt{2}) + 1)$ but this information hasn't helped me much, a part from making me believe that the inner integral should be of the form $\dfrac{1}{4} \dfrac{1}{1+f(x)}$.
For example I've thought about $(u,v) = (x, y^8)$, $(u,v) = (x^{1/3}, 1+y^8)$ but the  determinant of the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives becomes kind of ugly.

Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Fubini we get

$$\int_0^1 \left ( \int_{x^{1/3}}^1 (1+y^8)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dy \right ) dx=\int_0^1 \left ( \int_{0}^{y^3} (1+y^8)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx \right ) dy.$$

Hence you have to compute

$$\int_0^1(1+y^8)^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^3 dy.$$

Now use the substitution $u=y^4.$